# What is the negative of mustBe in Scalatest

Tags: scalatest

I am comfortable using `mustBe` in `Scalatest`. Eg.

```
A mustBe (Some(List(1)))
```

But how do I test something like `A must not be Some(anything here, done care what it is)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Negation](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#beingNegative) can be asserted on by simply adding the word `not` to the matcher expression, for example,

```
class So1Spec extends FlatSpec with MustMatchers {
  "BeingNegative" should "assert negation" in {
    1 must not be 2
  }
}
```